# Keeping text horizontal while it's position is rotating with d3.js

Tags: d3.js, text, rotation, element, label

I'm trying to add labels to the planets around the sun into this example : http://bl.ocks.org/djvanderlaan/4953593.
So far, I've managed to add the labels, but the orientation of the labels is rotating with their position, while I want to keep them horizontal for the comfort of the readers. 
I've been finding a beginning of a solution to my problem here : [how to keep text orientation unchanged during rotation in SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089341/how-to-keep-text-orientation-unchanged-during-rotation-in-svg) 
but it's seems very complicated to me (I am a newbie and really not good at trigonometry) and plus, it's not using d3.js.
Here is the code that I'am using :

```
<div id="planetarium">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var w = 800, h = 600;
  var t0 = Date.now();

  var planets = [
    { R: 300, r:  5, speed: 5, phi0: 90, name : 'Mercure'},
    { R: 150, r: 10, speed: 2, phi0: 190, name : 'Saturne'}
  ];


  var svg = d3.select("#planetarium").insert("svg")
    .attr("width", w).attr("height", h);

  svg.append("circle").attr("r", 20).attr("cx", w/2)
    .attr("cy", h/2).attr("class", "sun")

  var container = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + w/2 + "," + h/2 + ")")


  container.selectAll("g.planet").data(planets).enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "planet").each(function(d, i) {
      var orbit = d3.select(this).append("circle").attr("class", "orbit")
        .attr("r", d.R);
      var planet = d3.select(this).append("circle").attr("r", d.r).attr("cx",d.R)
        .attr("cy", 0).attr("class", "planet");
      var text = d3.select(this).append("text")
        .attr("x", d.R)
        .attr("y", ".31em")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; });


  d3.timer(function() {
    var delta = (Date.now() - t0);
    planet.attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "rotate(" + d.phi0 + delta * d.speed/200 + ")";
    });
    text.attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "rotate(" + d.phi0 + delta * d.speed/200 + ")";
    });
  });
 });

</script>
```

Here is my plunkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/dJEVXIeR7ly536tcMPWt?p=preview Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Use `sin()` and `cos()` like in my [example here](http://alkhoo-app.appspot.com/akfiddle/rotation_with_text.html).

Comment: I guess I will have to open that trigonometry handbook then, but thank you very much ;)

Comment: A way to avoid trig functions is to locate the centroid of a planet and figure out where exactly the text should be placed on the 8 compass points. Then extrapolate the other angles. Do use `text-anchor="middle"` and `getBBox()` as length of text affects the placement position.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found a solution inspired by this example : [D3.js: rotate group, keep text the same orientation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508172/d3-js-rotate-group-keep-text-the-same-orientation)
Instead of making two different variables for planets and text, I've gathered them in a same rotating group, and then added an inverse rotation on the text, but centered on the planet's center rather than the center of the container. Then I set both phi0 (the positions of the planets at the beginning of the animation) to 0, so that the text would be frozen horizontally. Here is my code :

```
var planets = [
    { R: 300, r:  5, speed: 5, phi0: 0, name : 'Mercure'},
    { R: 150, r: 10, speed: 2, phi0: 0, name : 'Saturne'}
  ];
//... 
var container = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + w/2 + "," + h/2 + ")")

  var orbit = container.selectAll(".orbit")
                       .data(planets)
                       .enter()
                       .append("circle")
                       .attr("class", "orbit")
                       .attr("r", function(d) {return d.R;});
  var planets = container.selectAll(".planet")
                       .data(planets)
                       .enter()
                       .append("g")

    planets.append("circle")
                       .attr("class", "planet")
                       .attr("r", function(d) {return d.r;})
                       .attr("cx", function(d) {return d.R; })
                       .attr("cy", 0);


    planets.append("text")
                       .attr("dx", function(d) {return d.R;})
                       .attr("dy", ".35em")
                       .text(function(d) {return d.name});


  d3.timer(function() {
    var delta = (Date.now() - t0);
    planets.attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "rotate(" + d.phi0 + delta * d.speed/200 + ")";
    });
    planets.selectAll("text").attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "rotate(" + -1*(d.phi0 + delta * d.speed/200) + " " + d.R + " " + 0 + ")";
    });
  });
```

Not sure this is a very good solution, but for the moment it works. I will learn trigonometry though, I promise ;)

Comment: Inverse Rotation for small dataset is a possible solution (and as long as it doesn't freeze the browsers, it is a "good enough" ).

Comment: @AlvinK. Have you got any other suggestion? I have a potentially big dataset and can't figure out how to do it...

Comment: @Joum: See my example in the comment section above, it is using basic trigonometry (high school level)